# How to apply a pagination in laravel API?

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-8, laravel-pagination

I developed one API(displayBlogs) which is responsible for getting data from database ,i want to apply pagination for displayBlogs api,for that i installed require package but i am unable to apply a pagination on that query(if i don't use get() method then pagination working) ,please help me to fix this issue..

`UserController.php`

```
 public function displayBlogs(){
        $user = new BlogModel();
        $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
        $id = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray();
        $user->user_id = $id["sub"];
        return DB::table('blogs_table')->where('user_id', $user->user_id)->get()->paginate(3);
    }
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

You need not to use the `get()` while using `paginate()`;

Answer (score 2):

just use paginate only

```
public function displayBlogs(){
    $user = new BlogModel();
    $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
    $id = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray();
    $user->user_id = $id["sub"];
    return DB::table('blogs_table')->where('user_id', $user->user_id)->paginate(3);
}
```